# Create Skype meeting event in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am creating events using the Microsoft Graph API
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

I am able to schedule meetings with other user. But now question is how I will communicate with that user on the scheduled day or time. 
can we add skype meeting as location while scheduling meeting? 
or any other way to communicate with the users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Today the **Skype for Business APIs are not exposed through the Microsoft Graph** and I doubt they will ever be considering Microsoft is investing heavily on Microsoft Teams.
As of today the Microsoft Teams APIs only allow you to CRUD [teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0), [manage tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsapp?view=graph-rest-1.0) and post [messages to channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatthreads?view=graph-rest-beta) (still beta).
**If you want to interact with Skype For Business you have to use the [UCWA API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/developingucwaapplicationsforsfbonline)** where you can [create a meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/onlinemeetingtasks).
Then you can update your Exchange Event with the S4B online meeting information so the users can access the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Microsoft Teams meeting call by adding in the body of your JSON a "contentType" : "HTML", 
"content": Call link https://aka/ms:mmkvlb"

This can be found  in the Graph Explorer page when you choose a POST method in "add graph community call", which is accessible in the Outlook Calendar Sample Category.

I think that you can also open this link with Skype.
For more information check: "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#"

Comment: Note that the "Call link" must be achieved from the method POST which you do in the "add graph community call"